# How to build external kernel module in yocto without the help of bitbake

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, driver, yocto

I compile a linux image with yocto branch dunfell and run in a x86-64 board. And I will compile my module in the x86-64 image directly.

And I want to compile my module with this image and run in the x86-64 board. For some reason, I dont want to write module recipe and compile the module by bitbake.

I add IMAGE_INSTALL_append += kernel-devsrc in yocto local.conf

I want to compile this module by make command directly. But I failed.

```
root@genericx86-64:~/mount_file/test_module# make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt/build M=/home/root/mount_file/test_module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt/build'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/root/mount_file/test_module/hello.o', needed by '__build'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1737: /home/root/mount_file/test_module] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt/build'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

These are my source code and makefile:

hello.c

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

kernel_src = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C ${kernel_src} M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C ${kernel_src} M=$(PWD) clean
```

This is my /lib/module/5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt/build

```
root@genericx86-64:~/mount_file/test_module# tree -aL 1 /lib/modules/5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt/build/
/lib/modules/5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt/build/
|-- .config
|-- Documentation
|-- Kconfig
|-- Makefile
|-- Module.symvers
|-- System.map-5.4.213-rt44-yocto-preempt-rt
|-- arch
|-- block
|-- certs
|-- crypto
|-- drivers
|-- fs
|-- include
|-- init
|-- ipc
|-- kernel
|-- lib
|-- localversion-rt
|-- mm
|-- net
|-- samples
|-- scripts
|-- security
|-- sound
|-- tools
|-- usr
`-- virt

21 directories, 6 files
```

Does anyone have the experience to compile external kernel module in yocto without the help of bitbake. That is, compile the module by set kernel source path in Makefile and make directly. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. Assuming you are building your module into the same source code directory, you might be missing to prepare build area.

Try calling `scripts modules_prepare` targets previous to `modules` one. This will set up your build dir. for external modules compilation.

```
make scripts modules_prepare
make
```

Comment: Oh, that is my lack of building linux kernel experience. Your answer is effective. Thanks a lot !!!